# How to bind DataTable to DataGridView as a DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a `DataTable` and I insert a `Row` using `DataColumnCollection`, and then bind to the `DataSource`.  Afterwards, I saw in the grid's first column `System.Data.DataColumnCollection` that the value is not present. Give me an idea.

Comment: You description is a bit hard to follow; can you illustrate with sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it,

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("No",typeof(int)); // Adding column into ColumnsCollection
dt.Columns.Add("Name");

dt.Rows.Add(1,"AAA");  // Adding rows into RowsCollection
dt.Rows.Add(2,"BBB");

DataGridView1.DataSource=dt; // Binding datasource
```